# Prevent Kendo grid data bind events when updating multiple model properties

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I'm updating multiple properties on a Kendo datasource row model (using model.set javascript), and I want the grid to update only after the last change is made.

Another issue is that i don't know (without many if statements) whether any of the properties actually changed.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I would suggest you do something like this: [Inline Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-inline.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I pulled off the Kendo Forum:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

grid.bind("dataBinding", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
//begin modifying the data
//.....
//finish modifying the data
grid.unbind("dataBinding");
grid.refresh();
```

Comment: This seemed like a winner but didn't work for me :( Stupid grid happily loads the datasource anyway.